# Div doesnt animate of completely of the screen

Tags: jquery

Ok when i run this jquery code, I basically am clicking a picture and a div slides in and when I press the escape key or click outside the div nothing happens... But I also want to slide the div in if i click the picture again which it does. The problem is if i click the div again it slides in immediately with out staying afloat..

The jquery code :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".mirror_content").hide(); 
    $('#mir_way').on('click' , function() {
        $('#mir_way').toggle(function(){ 
            $('#mirror').stop().animate({width:"1109px", opacity: 1 ,  margin: "0 235px 0 0"}, 100, function() {
                $('.mirror_content').fadeIn('slow'); 
            });  

            $(window).on('keyup', function(event) {
                if(event.which === 27) {
                    $('.mirror_content').fadeOut('slow', function() { 
                        $('#mirror').stop().animate({width:"0", opacity:0.1}, 100);
                    });
                }
            });

            $(window).on('mouseup', function (e)
            {
                var container = $("#mirror");

                if (container.has(e.target).length === 0)
                {
                    $('.mirror_content').fadeOut('slow', function() {  
                        $('#mirror').stop().animate({width:"0", opacity:0.1}, 100);    
                    }); 
                }
            });
        }, function(){ 
            $('.mirror_content').fadeOut('slow', function() { 
                $('#mirror').stop().animate({width:"0", opacity:0.1}, 100); 
            });
        });
    }).trigger('click');
});
```

Comment: Can you provide a working example on jsfiddle.net?

Comment: jsfiddle doesnt give an output :/

Comment: huh? add some html so we know what you're working with

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/NZR6Y/ 

@cgatian : The animation is not right in jfiddle. Well i will explain u better. The click that i have put up is the picture and when i click it a div slides from the right and when i press escape or click outside the div the slided in div fadesOut and if i click the image again the div shows up and when i click on the image again to slide in it slides in but is still visible on the right part of my screen... Need screenshots?

Comment: So you're saying the fiddle works?

Comment: My code shows an output in my webpage am designing but the fiddle doesnt show the exact output of my code. It shows a crappy div box which slides out from the right and doesnt slide in.

Comment: jsfiddle wont work exact match to your code with half the code... you talk about images etc.. you jsfiddle has no image... if you need help. you have to show relevent code.

Comment: Thats all the code @rahul : The only thing i have left of is the image which is not relevant... The div which slides has content and images on it and those are the ones that is visible when it slides to the right back on to the place where it came from. but it giving me problems as it doesnt completely hide. Can u come to pvt chat on fb? i need help really.. maybe i can send some screenies thr

Comment: well i dotn have access to FB at my work..

Comment: WHat is the toggle function you added to `jquery fn` Only in  `jsfiddle` ?

Comment: Since toggle is deprecated in 1.9.1 and I dunno exactly how to use Jquery migrator , I just used some code which is a replaces the new toggle function with old toggle function. I used that explicity in Jsfiddle since  I wanted the toggle in my code to work...